# Still root after logout,why?

Tags: linux, bash

```
[root@ ]# logout
There are stopped jobs.
[root@ ]#
```

So I need to `logout` twice to actually logout.

When will this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the shell still has jobs stopped in the background. Use `jobs` to see the current jobs, and `fg %<n>` to bring a job to the foreground so that you can end it.

Comment: so the 1st logout is false,it actually just terminates the background jobs?

Comment: It makes you aware that there are background jobs. The second actually closes the shell.

Comment: It says `There are stopped jobs.` but actually never prints them out...isn't this weird?

Comment: It's your, uh, job to determine whether or not you care about them.

Comment: locale: ... and you can use "jobs -l" to see what the stopped jobs actually are.

Answer (score 2):

You're being prevented from logging out because you've suspended a task during your console session, probably using CTRL-Z. This task is still active, but suspended in the background.

The `fg` command will bring the task back to the foreground and allow you to kill it, or figure out what's going on.